# Routes not working in an express app using Jade to generate static html files

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, pug

Hi I'm trying to create my first node app / environment.

App structure

```
MyApp/
-node_modules/
-public/
--images/
--javascript/
--scss/
-routes/
-source/
--images/
--javascript/
--scss/
-views/
-gulp.js
-app.js
-package.json
```

I'm using the following to run my app:

Using Node
gulp as a task manager (sass, jshint, jade to html)
Jade as template
Express (server and routes)

Maybe worth to mention that I'm using gulp to generate html files from my jade templates.

My issue is with the routes, I cannot make the routes work, I run gulp which process all my task and start node app.js which start the server.

Here is my code for gulp.js

```
/* file: gulpfile.js */

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    express = require('express'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    sass   = require('gulp-sass'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade');


// Server and live reload ==========================

gulp.task('express', function() {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 35729}));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
});

var tinylr;
gulp.task('livereload', function() {
  tinylr = require('tiny-lr')();
    tinylr.listen(35729);
});

function notifyLiveReload(event) {
  var fileName = require('path').relative(__dirname, event.path);

  tinylr.changed({
    body: {
      files: [fileName]
    }
  });
}


// Task templates jade =============================

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('views/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
             pretty: true
        })) // pip to jade plugin
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/')); // tell gulp our output folder
});


// SASS and Minify ==================================

var onError = function (err) {  
  gutil.beep();
  console.log(err);
};


gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: onError
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())  // Process the original sources
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // Add the map to modified source.
    .pipe(autoprefixer(
        {
            browsers: [
                '> 1%',
                'last 2 versions',
                'firefox >= 4',
                'safari 7',
                'safari 8',
                'IE 8',
                'IE 9',
                'IE 10',
                'IE 11'
            ],
            cascade: false
        }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/styles/'));
});



// Javascript concat and uglify ============================= 

gulp.task('build-js', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/javascript/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascript'));
});

//  Images Taks optimization ================================

gulp.task('images', function(){
  return gulp.src('source/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({
      interlaced: true
    })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/images'))
});


// Watch task ==================================================

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('source/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('source/javascript/**/*.js', ['build-js']);
  gulp.watch('./views/**/*.jade', ['html']);
  gulp.watch('./public/*.html', notifyLiveReload);
  gulp.watch('./views/**/*.jade',  notifyLiveReload);
  gulp.watch('./public/styles/*.css', notifyLiveReload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'styles', 'express', 'build-js', 'livereload', 'watch'], function() {

});
```

Here is my app.js

```
// BASE SETUP ===============================================

'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// var routes = require('./routes/index');

// CONFIGURATION ============================================

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// app.use('/', routes);


// CREATE SERVER ============================================

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App started in port 3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Hi James,

Thanks for your answer! I'm pretty new in node coming from php so i think I got a bit confuse with the routes...

So as far as I understand you, it's not worthy to use gulp to render html pages better to keep using jade since is dynamic, makes sense.

I try your code but now it throws me an error:  Cannot find module 'jade'

Can you point me to a good tutorial or give me a bit more of insight please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: make sure to `npm install jade` and include it in the file.   You can either declare `var jade = require('jade')` at the top of your app file or inline it with `app.set('view engine', require('jade'))`

Comment: also to clarify, the dynamic routing solution doesn't provide any caching, and some would argue that using res.render in production can be a performance hit vs just sending cached precompiled files.  There are a few different ways  to make that more performant, but my main concern is just getting things to work first.  That's a discussion for another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use jade as the view engine in express, you can do away with the gulp compile of your jade files. This is an unnecessary step.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

these lines tell express to use jade when calling `render()` within the router.  As you set up your routes, whether they be root `app.get('/', function(req, res){})` or something else - just call `res.render('viewname')` for express to take over from there.  It will invoke the jade compiler at the time the request fires and return the html output.  This allows for you to insert an object as the second argument of render and pass in dynamic data.

example breakout here:

assuming you set `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` this tells express to look into the /views directory for jade files when you call `render('home')` for example.  You do not need to specify '/views/home.jade' or anything like that.  If you have nested folders within /views, it becomes your root, so calling `render('/subfolder/nested')` will work.

```
/views
- home.jade
- secondary.jade
  /subfolder
  - nested.jade
```

sample routes for the views above

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //do some sort of preprocessing here if you want
  res.render('home');
})

app.post('/secondary', function(req, res){
  //do some sort of preprocessing here if you want
  res.render('secondary', {somedata: 'this is data'});
})
```

note the second argument to render is an object.  From within secondary.jade, you now have access to somedata as a variable.  You could for instance set the title to be whatever somedata is

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title=somedata
  body
```

the title would come out as 'this is data'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your answer! I'm pretty new in node coming from php so i think I got a bit confuse with the routes... So as far as I understand you, it's not worthy to use gulp to render html pages better to keep using jade since is dynamic, makes sense. 


I try your code but now it throws me an error: Cannot find module 'jade' Can you point me to a good tutorial or give me a bit more of insight please. Thanks a lot!